# Does C++ 11 thread automatically destroy after detach

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, thread-safety

Normally, I would assume that C++ 11 thread automatically destroy after detach. But the thing is, I can't find anything to prove this assumption.

According to [this article](http://www.bogotobogo.com/cplusplus/C11/1_C11_creating_thread.php)

> Once detached, the thread should live that way forever.

forever? If the function of the thread finish, Does its resource remain forever?

According to [this article](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/thread/thread/detach/)

> After a call to this function, the thread object becomes non-joinable and can be destroyed safely.

It can be destroyed safely, but is it automatically?

If it's not destroyed automatically, how to destroy it (not forcefully, but after the function of the thread end)

Thanks for reading.

Comment: Whether the thread object is destroyed automatically or not depends on what its storage duration is.

Comment: @ Captain Obvlious: ah, I get it, C++ 11 also check if the resource is safe to decide if destroy thread or not - C++ 11 so awesome :)

Comment: @Nicol Bolas: I got it, thank you, from now on, I'll use http://en.cppreference.com

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You should consult a better reference. From [`std::thread::detach`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/detach):

> Separates the thread of execution from the thread object, allowing execution to continue independently. Any allocated resources will be freed once the thread exits.
>
> After calling detach `*this` no longer owns any thread.

So to answer your questions (if they aren't already):

> forever?

No. If the thread finishes (for example: if it counts to 10), it is done and it is not running anymore.

> Does its resource remain forever?

No, when the thread finishes, every resource from the thread is freed (like variables and such).

> It can be destroyed safely, but is it automatically?

What do you mean? When the thread is done, it is destroyed (automatically), regardless of whether you call `detach` or not. The only difference is that here, they are referring to the thread *object*, so the actual `std::thread` instance.

So when the thread object is destructed, you must have called `join` or `detach` regardless whether you own that the actual thread finished or not. If you don't, `std::terminate` is called.

Comment: In the 'It can be destroyed safely, but is it automatically?' -> I means to ask about the automatically :) anyway, you totally answer that question, thank you very much :)

Comment: Can you make me clear how the local variables of a detached thread still exist while the main program has exited? I cannot understand it !

Comment: @hsalimi they don't? when the main thread exits, the program just stops.

Comment: "allowing execution to continue independently" --> I mean how the detached thread can continue independantly while the process has existed? How is it possible?

Comment: @hsalimi no it can't. If the process exits then every thread is destroyed.

Answer (score 2):

A std::thread is just a thin wrapper around your platform's native threading library... It doesn't really contain much internally besides a few flags and the native handle to the platform's thread representation (which for both Unix & Windows is a fancy integral identifier). Speaking specifically of Unix-like systems, the call to std::thread::detach() does two things:

- calls some variation of pthread_detach(), which frees a data structure used to store the returning void pointer from platform-native thread-main.
- sets a flag in the class denoting that the thread has been detached, and that, in turn, prevents the destructor from throwing an exception.

As for any other resources that the thread creation may set up, those should be cleaned up by your platform's run-time when your thread-main exits.

So, putting it another way, std::thread::detach just allows the wrapper to be destroyed without throwing an exception; the actual thread's stack and OS resource reclamation happens in the thread's execution context after your thread's main function exits, and that should be 100% automatic.